# How do i hide a block of HTML code in joomla from all other pages except for the Homepage

Tags: joomla2.5

I have done it before in joomla 1.5 but i cant recall how to do it in joomla 2.5, i know it involves a php if statement.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 2.5 do the following:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```

It gets a little more complicated with multilingual sites. It is fully described in the [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this can be achieved easily by creating a new HTML module from your admin control panel and inserting your HTML code in it.

How to create a custom HTML module: http://www.joomlatutorials.com/joomla-tips-and-tricks/38-joomla-website-management/102-create-a-custom-html-joomla-module.html

Then you can easily set where your module is visible (menu assignment option 'On all pages except those selected' and your home menu item selected) without having to hack your template.